Conectar Pentaho con Sql Server
Buen dia a todos
He estado batallando para conectar Pentaho Data Integration (9.3) con Sql server 2008 development version, actualmente existe una conexión exitosa en otra maquina con las mismas características, ya copie toda la carpeta de pentaho, tengo los drivers de conexión, tengo las variables de entorno, pero me aparece un mensaje de error al momento de querer consultar las tablas (digo consultar porque al darle test, no me muestra ningún error y no hace nada)
ya vi este post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964224/connect-pentaho-to-ms-sql-server-native
pero no me funciona

Te aparece un mensaje de error ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error? ¿Por qué estás usando una versión obsoleta sin soporte en vez de una actual?

@LuisCazares me aparece este error: Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
El controlador no pudo establecer una conexión segura con SQL Server con el cifrado de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL). Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:b6dcfea7-2cbf-4f16-8ecd-b481611b6e96
